# Free flash to video convertor

Tags: video, flash

Recently I've needed to convert an SWF file to a video file(basically any other format will do), but almost no software supports this, or it's really bad quality, so I came here.

All the "shapes" of the flash file are SVG "files" so flash players in Chrome, MPC-HC and the Flash Player projector basically turn it into a higher resolution.

I want (the name of) a program that can:

1. turn SVG files into video files of a higher resolution than the SWF file dimensions
2. run on Windows 10
3. be in English or maybe Dutch
4. be free
5. be able to export to a lossless avi file (not really needed but it would be nice)
6. be able to take the audio as well (not really needed either, but would be nice)

Ok, so I got After Effects to import it and "render" it, but it was only 480×360 because that is the "stage" an changing the "scale" property just scaled it up as it was.

I've also tried:

- FFmpeg (just showed the first asset in the SWF file with the sound playing over it)
- Handbrake (same as FFmpeg)
- Vlc (showed the same as FFmpeg, did not try to use it to convert it)
- FFDec to turn it into a fla file and open it in:

  Adobe Animate (misaligned some shapes)

  Adobe Flash CS3 (didn't recognise the fla file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [FFDec](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/releases) to remove the Protected tag in the SWF file and then imported it into [Adobe Animate](https://www.adobe.com/products/animate.html) and then was able to export it to everything [Adobe Media Encoder](https://www.adobe.com/products/media-encoder.html) supports.